# %d Error While Calling String

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
i = i + 1
print '%d Codes Grabbed' (i)
```

This is the part of the code not working for my Python script, it is placed in a loop so every loop it should just say an amount of Codes Grabbed (ex: 5 Codes Grabbed) Except this %d is not working for some reason. Also this is the error which really doesn't help me understand at all:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:[CENSORED]", line 21, in <module>
    print '%d Codes Grabbed' (i)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So I would like to know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whenever you get a "is not callable" error, that means you have parentheses after a variable or literal where  you meant to have something else in between.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `%`

```
i = i + 1
print '%d Codes Grabbed'%(i)
```

This will print (if `i` is 10)

```
11 Codes Grabbed
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a simple mistake...

Comment: @DarkPirate Yes it was a very simple mistake. Happy to help.

Comment: Also I am having an odd regex problem, I want to append just the code portion to my .txt file but instead I get a [n' before and '] after the code (This is the string regex is being used on: {"message":"Code available","code":"P3T947YMKNEJ","responseCode":200,"promoCodeLink":" and this is my regex: re.findall(r'"Code available","code":"(.*?)","responseCode"',html)

Comment: @DarkPirate Appreciate your doubt. But as it is not related to this question do ask a separate question.

Comment: Alright will do, also will mark your answer as the correct one in a few mins (I have a timer..)

Answer (score 1):

you need a `%` before `i` :

```
print '%d Codes Grabbed'%i
```

or you can use `format` function :

```
print '{} Codes Grabbed'.format(i)
```

> The [% operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) can also be used for string formatting. It interprets the left argument much like a sprintf()-style format string to be applied to the right argument, and returns the string resulting from this formatting operation

Comment: Isn't that the same as Bhargav Rao's answer?

Comment: @PythonMaster, They posted their answer same time.

Comment: @PythonMaster there is just few second difference , aslo answers are not same !

Comment: @PythonMaster Yeah, We both posted it in a second's difference

Comment: Oh, that's why your answers were so similar and almost the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

You have missing %

```
print '%d Codes Grabbed' % i
```

some people might recommend [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function as of 2.6

```
print "{0} Codes Grabbed".format(i)
```